# Power Query M string to datetime conversion

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures, powerquery

I'm trying to invoke a stored proc with a nullable datetime value, but I'm running in circles with this. Below you can see all the combinations I've tried and the related errors:

```
FromDate = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FromDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
FromDateQuery = if FromDate = "" then "" else "@FromDate = '"& DateTime.From(FromDate)&"',",

Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and DateTime.
Details:
    Operator=&amp;
    Left=@FromDate = &#39;
    Right=15/03/2017 00:00:00
```

If I follow the instructions and remove the & as suggested I get the following:
Expression.SyntaxError: Token Comma expected.

Tried passing it through as a string:

```
FromDate = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FromDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
FromDateQuery = if FromDate = "" then "" else "@FromDate = '"& Text.From(FromDate) &"',",
```

Message=Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Query:

```
[Query="EXECUTE dbo.bsp_GetReport
"& UserQuery &"
"& FromDateQuery &"]
```

Also tried using Cast and Convert all in vain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTime.ToText with the required formatting, e.g.

```
FromDateQuery = if FromDate = "" then "" else "@FromDate = '"& DateTime.ToText(DateTime.From(FromDate), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")&"',",
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this also returns: "Error converting data type varchar to datetime." I'm going to update my original question with details on how I call the stored proc

Comment: I don't know why, but after I swapped the date format to be yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss it works... (FYI I'm not using this format anywhere)

Comment: That error is coming from the SQL database. You need to use the datetime format that the database understands.